# External HTML asset not bundled by React Native in production build for use by Webview

Tags: android, ios, webview, react-native

I'm building an Android application using React Native. It has a webview that reads an HTML file locally.

This is the piece of code I'm using to render webview.

```
<WebView ref="webview"
      source={require('./helloworld.html')}
      javaScriptEnabled style={styles.webView} />
```

This works well during development build. The HTML file loads on the webview and renders well.

But it doesn't on Android release/production build. The webview is empty and if I inspect using chrome://inspect, the webview is empty and doesn't load the HTML file.

From what I understand is the React Native fails to bundle helloworld.html as an asset during Android production build. I noticed that it works fine on iOS.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the discussions around here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6004, it's a known defect. Assets are not bundled for Android production build but works fine in dev build.

A solution is store assets in Android assets folder manually, and then load the resource using

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/helloworld.html' }}
    startInLoadingState={true} />
```

Comment: @ParthPandya This solution is only for Android. For iOS, you can use the regular way as mentioned in the question.

Comment: For android this works unless you need to inject a script. For me, the injected script doesn't run.

Comment: @TimScott look at the last comment [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16133) for the solution to that problem:

Answer (score 0):

on RN 0.40,

```
require('./file.html')
```

is failing for me in Build release variant. It's fine in debug builds.

As workaround, I was able to put the file in android assets dir, and

```
{ uri: file:///android_asset/file.html }
```

load from there. Unfortunately for my situation, the html file loads remote third-party libs which internally reference protocol-agnostic resources: e.g., `//domain.com/file.json`. So those all got turned into `file://domain.com/file.json` links and of course failed.
I monkey patched `XMLHttpRequest` to change //... to https://... which solved that problem, but none of the images those libs attempt to load, will load. all broken. And I've been unable to find a way to determine what the requests look like for those images, to see why they break/fail-to-load.

Answer (score -1):

on iOS production build this solution is work

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: 'helloworld.html' }}
    startInLoadingState={true} />
```